# Flatten JSON array of objects that contain an array with Jolt

Tags: json, jolt

I'm using Jolt 0.1.0, and trying to transform the following JSON:

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "collectionId": "COLLECTION1",
      "recordIds": [
        "recA",
        "recB"
      ]
    },
    {
      "collectionId": "COLLECTION1",
      "recordIds": [
        "recC",
        "recD",
        "recE"
      ]
    },
    {
      "collectionId": "COLLECTION2",
      "recordIds": [
        "recF",
        "recG"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

... to this:

```
{
  "records": [
    "COLLECTION1:recA",
    "COLLECTION1:recB",
    "COLLECTION1:recC",
    "COLLECTION1:recD",
    "COLLECTION1:recE",
    "COLLECTION2:recF",
    "COLLECTION2:recG"
  ]
}
```

I've made several attempts with the modify-default-beta operator and the concat function, but can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/issues/656 which required 4 steps.